# test if file is valid FASTA using grep (i.e. full file matching single regular expression)

Tags: regex, linux, grep, fasta

What is a simple way to test if given file is valid FASTA:

valid_example.fasta

```
>genename1 atgcgtcactgNNNNNactgat
>genename 2 ACACTTACAGGGCTAC

>genename3 ATCCaACTACGGCTGGACTTGCGGCAT
```

I tried the following, but it would give a match if there's at least 1 valid gene, as opposed to all of them

```
grep -Pli "(>.+\n[atgcn]\n+)*" valid_example.fasta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-v` flag to invert the match.  Then check to see if any lines match.

You might want to do like

```
grep -qv [other options] [pattern] $file || echo $file matches
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex to nucleotide fasta format:

```
>.+\n[acgtnACGTN\n]+
```